# GeckoFX with CORS support

Tags: c#, javascript, xmlhttprequest, cors, geckofx

We have a desktop applicaton for private usage. This is build in C# and use GeckoFX for UI (HTML, JavaScript). We need to allow CORS, but we don't have control in webserver...

In a previous version, we use the default WebBrowser Control, what use IE for rendering. In the IE, there is a options for allow CORS (Security Settings, Miscellaneous/Access Data Sources Across Domains) but we have to use GeckoFX insted of IE.

Is there any solution to allow cross domain request in this special browser without any JS hack or proxy?

**Update:**
There is an easy way in chrome, start witt `--disable-web-security` flag. Is there something similar in Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

CORS is serverside generated HTTP header. Without control over server you cannot use it.
Since you cannot access server you have to hack GeckoFX source code. Luckily source available http://code.google.com/p/geckofx/source/checkout

Comment: I know, but this limitation is in only in modern browser. In IE with the mentioned settings and old browsers you can make xhr request without control.